# How to run Bash Script on startup and keep monitoring the results on the terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, startup, linux-mint

Due to some issues I wont elaborate here to not waste time, I made a **bash script** which will ping google every 10 minutes and if there is a response it will keep the loop running and if not then the PC will restart. After a lot of hurdle I have been able to make the script and also make it start on bootup. However the issue is that **i want to see the results on the terminal**, meaning I want to keep monitoring it but the terminal does not open on bootup. But it does open if I run it as `./net.sh`.
The script is running on startup, that much I know because I use another script to open an application and it works flawlessly.

My system information

```
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="18.3 (Sylvia)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 18.3"
VERSION_ID="18.3"
HOME_URL="http://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://forums.linuxmint.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/"
VERSION_CODENAME=sylvia
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

The contents of my **net.sh** bash script are

```
#! /bin/bash

xfce4-terminal &

sleep 30

while true
do
        ping -c1 google.com
        if [ $? == 0 ]; then
                echo "Ping Sucessful. The Device will Continue Operating"
                sleep 600
        else
                systemctl reboot
        fi

done
```

I have put the scripts in `/usr/bin` and inserted the scripts for startup at boot in `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: This should help: https://superuser.com/a/1302626

Comment: Is a terminal really necessary? you may consider logging your output to a textfile

Comment: Thanks everyone. A little late in responding but I have found a fix that worked for me. I am new to the site so I dont know how to tag someone. 
@Diego Torres Milano thank you for your comment but I already went through that beforehand but I couldnt understand it. I needed a more specific answer.

Comment: @Flo thank you. I just like the look of terminal thats why. If it was possibe to read the text file in terminal in real time then that would have worked too but I dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

So I did some further research and with help from reddit I realized that the reason I couldnt get it to show on terminal was because the script was starting on bootup but I needed it to start after user login. So I added the script on startup application (which can be found searching on start menu if thats whats it called). But it was still giving issues so I divided the script in two parts.
I put the `net.sh` script on startup and directed that script to open my main script which i named `net_loop.sh`

This is how the **net.sh** script looks

```
#! /bin/bash
    
sleep 20
xfce4-terminal -e usr/bin/net_loop.sh
```

And the **net_loop.sh**

```
#! /bin/bash

while true
do
        ping -c1 google.com
        if [ $? == 0 ]; then
                echo "Ping Sucessful. The Device will Continue Operating"
                sleep 600
        else
                systemctl reboot
        fi

done
```

The results are the results of the **net_loop.sh** script are open in another terminal.
**Note**: I used help from this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565284/how-to-open-a-terminal-in-bash-script-and-continue-running-script)

Comment: you can do `if ping -c1 google.com; then ...` and rebooting seems a bit drastic for a missing packet and if you reboot the script could be silent (not terminal, no output) as you will notice immediately when ping fails and the output is useless

Answer (score 0):

If minute interval is usable why not use "cron" to start your?

$> crontab –e

or

$> sudo crontab –e